# Gradle, check if Git branch exists

Tags: git, gradle

Somehow I have been thrown into the world of `Gradle`... don't know it, don't like it... I am a `.Net` web developer who they threw a mac at and told me to become a dev ops engineer (big read flashing sign that I need to move on)... so please cut me some slack on the dumb questions here...

```
task createBranch(type:Exec, dependsOn: cloneRepo) {
    def branch = "Projects/" + ant.svnprojectversion + "/" + ant.bundleidentifier
    def branchPath = new File(branch)

    commandLine "git", "checkout", "develop"
    commandLine "git", "branch", "-d", branchPath
    println 'Delete Branch'

    //commandLine "git", "checkout", "-b", branchPath
    //println 'Create new local branch at' + branchPath
}
```

I am also new to `Git`... I need to somehow check if a local "branch" already exists. If it doesn't, I need to create it, which I already know how to do, otherwise, I need to do something else, not quite sure what that will be but that is a separate question.

So, how can I check if a branch already exists?? I know in git I can do the git show-branch, but I don't know how to get a response back from the commandLine in gradle. I am trying not to use a plug in since I have already gone down that path with no success most likely due to my lack of experience. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

After finding and reading more about EXEC in the gradle documentation, http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html. I found a setting named "ignoreExitValue", that when set to true, will ignore the command line errors and continue to run all the gradle tasks in their order. So, I used this to create the new branch and ignore the error if the  branch already exists, then the next task will checkout the branch. I won't mark this as the official answer until I am certain this is an okay solution. Plus, there are some other settings in the gradle doc I may play around with as well.